# Dress code at an office in Finland

Tags: dress-code

I am a Singaporean.

I will be sent to Finland for training. I would like to know their dress code working at an office.

Answer (score 3):

There's almost certainly a large spread in how casual/formal individual offices are.  You're going to have to ask someone involved with the training.  Either a your boss or local coworker who's been there before; or your point of contact for the trip on the far side.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked in several countries.

A general rule of thumb is that as a foreigner dress formally and sensibly. You need to make a professional impression from your first day since you will be under scrutiny. So I would advise you to dress a notch above the locals once you find out what they're wearing, but for your first days dress formally.

The last time I was in Singapore the fashion was incredibly short mini skirts, don't wear anything like that.

Comment: "formally and sensibly" could mean almost anything.

Comment: How do you work that out? Formally means not casual, sensibly means things like not wearing stiletto heels if you expect to be doing much walking. When I had meetings in Singapore the men showed up in suits, the women in knee length skirts and blouses, pretty much OK anywhere in the World I would think.

Comment: So you mean "men in suits, women in knee length skirts and blouses"? Is that "formal and sensible" in Finland?

Comment: I assume common sense in the OP which is why I didn't specify the exact clothing, I also assume common sense in commenters....

Comment: Wow, nice comment on your part... I was just trying to understand what you wrote. FWIW, your answer would be better if you avoid "formally and sensibly" and substituted "men in suits, women in knee length skirts and blouses". You're welcome.

Comment: na... you were just typing rubbish... everyone knows the difference between formal clothing and 'pretty much anything'... no offence ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40168/discussion-between-kilisi-and-workerdrone).

Comment: Not interested in debating my comments.